# System.Collections missing / saving Listbox data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm having an issue that I have never ran into before, but at the same time have never tried. 
I'm trying to make an Injector and everything was fine and dandy until I tried to save the Listbox data which holds the DLL to inject data(there may be multiple DLLs at once), the reason i'm having trouble is because I can't just save the text, I have to save all the Item data. They way I went about this was just to in the Properties of the project(I'm using VS 2013) and create an ArrayList setting to save the data to. But here's the issue... For some reason I don't even have an option for ArrayList under the "Type" of setting. I looked it up and if you click "Browse" and open "System.Collections" it should be in there... but it's not! I've tried importing it in the namespace, no go. I'm coding this project in VB.net and if we cant solve this issue does anyone else have any alternatives to the way i'm going about it? If possible I would like to not create any external files to store data in! Thanks in advanced!

Cheers!

Comment: at the bottom just type in `System.Collections.Arraylist` but there is no reason the standard `StringCollection` would not work just as well, probably better (arraylist will return object, the standard string collection will return ... strings).  In the future, please try to throw in a paragraph break or two.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Plutonix! I'm going to assume "at the bottom" is referring to the Browse option under "Type" which sadly did nothing.